# I'm having an issue with appending the output of wmic to a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, append, wmic

I have a batch file that runs when any user logs on to the domain. The batch file gets lots of diffrent information from the users PC and outputs it into a text file on a shared folder.
In part of the batch file i use WMIC to get the Product Name and Serial Number of the PC.

My issue is when i output the Product Name and Serial Number using the below code the font size is massive.

Code

```
wmic bios get serialnumber >> A:\"%username%".txt
wmic csproduct get name >> A:\"%username%".txt
```

Output

```
S e r i a l N u m b e r     *********          N a m e    **********
```

and when i tried using the following it doesnt work for users with a space in there name  even if i add quotes

```
EG:
%username% = "Joe blogs" doesnt work
%username% = jblogs works fine
```

Code

```
wmic /APPEND:A:\"%username%".txt bios get serialnumber >> nul
wmic /APPEND:A:\"%username%".txt csproduct get name >> nul
```

So in short i need a way of changing the font of the output or a way of making wmic /append work for users with a space in there name.

If anyone needs more info or needs me to clarify something let me know
Thanks

Comment: could you check if the this will resolve your issue -> http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266  ?

Comment: That Link did help a bit, thats the kind of format im looking for but it works when i run it from the prompt directly but when i added it to the batch script i get "B was unexpected at this time" any ideas ?

Comment: [Noodles](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3914475/noodles) answer is helpful as it corrects syntax problem. But using `wmic` with option `/APPEND` will result in an output file with most lines ending with 0D 0A (carriage return + line-feed), but some lines with 0D 0A 0A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wmic /APPEND:"A:\%username%.txt" bios get serialnumber >> nul
```

Your quotes are wrong. A: is reserved for floppy drives.